# is it possible to code microservo automatically stop when the speed of rotation getting slower?

Tags: motor, servo

my group is doing a project which call automatic bed maker. we want to use a servomotor to pull the sheet of the bed. can we possibly make the servomotor stop rotate when the speed of rotation decrease? or is there any way to make the servo motor automatically stop beside using timer.
sorry for broken english.

Comment: Not without feedback to the MCU.

Comment: Is this a very small model to show the idea? What is causing the speed of the servo to slow down? A standard microservo is only going to have a very small movement, and it is easier to get information from a DC motor with motor drive than from a continuous rotation servo.